# Scala spark how to fix this task is not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So I have a simple UDF

```
object Constants extends Serializable {
  val COMMA_DELIMITER: String = ","
  val EMPTY: String = " "
 }

val Format2Int = (input: AnyRef) => {
  var column = input.toString.trim()
  column = column.replaceAll(Constants.COMMA_DELIMITER, Constants.EMPTY).trim()
  column
}

sqlContext.udf.register("Format2Int", Format2Int)
```

This returns a task is not serializable whenever I attempt to call it, because of the use of `Constants` object. (If I replace `Constants.COMMA_DELIMITER` and `Constants.EMPTY` it works just fine.  How can I fix this while still using the Constants class?

Comment: I can't reproduce this (works well for me) - using vals from objects should be safe. Is the `Constants` object an inner object in some other class by any chance?

Comment: Nope.  Might be a databricks specific issue then (since I am using databricks spark)

Comment: @test acc this is because when you do `Constants.COMMA_DELIMITER` you are referencing the field from the serialized obj. If you do something like, `val a = Constants.COMMA_DELIMITER` you're using a local copy

Comment: @ChitralVerma Is there anyway to fix this issues? I added `val a = Constants.COMMA_DELIMITER` and then called `a` in my uses, but still got the same error.

Comment: you have to use it directly. Although, `String` is `Serializable` by default, so not sure why there s error in the first place

Comment: @ChitralVerma I tried both using it directly and declaring a variable and using it, neither worked.